# Save the output result of observeEvent to a reactive variable in R Shiny

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity

How do I store the output of an `observeEvent()` to a reactive variable? For example, I want the user to upload a file, click Submit, and when they click Submit, I want to store the results of that file to a reactive variable. I tried just assigning it as a reactive to a variable and it didn't work.

Here's a quick example of my app and what I tried:

```
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("json", "Upload json", multiple = T),
  actionButton("submit", "Submit),
  verbatimTextOutput("check")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  list <- reactive({
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
    files <- req(input$json)
    data <- map(files, read_json)
    data
 })
})
  output$check <- renderPrint(list())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Have a look at `eventReactive`, i.e. `list <- eventReactive(input$submit, { ... } )`

Comment: I knew it had to be simple. New to Shiny. Thank you so much!

Comment: As an alternative you could stick with `reactive` and use it along with `bindEvent()` (also check `bindCache()`). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `reactiveValues` function to store reactive values. Then you can re-use `rv$file_text` in any part of you code or change the state of this reactive variable.

```
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("json", "Upload json", multiple = T),
  actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
  verbatimTextOutput("check")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    
  rv <- reactiveValues(file_text = NULL)
  
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    
    req(input$submit)
    req(input$json$datapath)
    
    json_list <- fromJSON(input$json$datapath)
    
    rv$file_text <- as.character(json_list)
    
  })
  
  output$check <- renderText({ 
    
    req(rv$file_text)
    rv$file_text 
    
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```